# Apply checkJs to inline JS in cshtml

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor

I've got a asp.net core project in Visual Studio and some inline JavaScript in a `*.cshtml` file.
I'm trying to apply TypeScript checks to the JS, but neither `// @ts-check` nor a `jsconfig.json` file with `"checkJs": true` do the trick.
Those methods work in plain `*.js` and `*.html` files.

Does someone have an idea how to fix this strange behavior?

Comment: Can you share the configuration and sample code?

Comment: Just create a new `asp.net core` project. The js settings do not apply to inline javascript inside a `*.cshtml` file...

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/javascript-errors-are-not-marked-with-the-red-unde/1567476